# FIELD_FILTER_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION, Competitor Required: Value does not exist or does not match filter criteria

Tags: account, validation-rule, lookup-filter

we have lookup relationship called as 'Competitor' on opportunity object where it gives the account of record type competitor and in the filter criteria it gives only those competitor account whose status is Active.

Now the problem is when the user add any active competitor account on opportunity and after some times if he inactivate the account,it throws the above error mentioned in the heading on VF page in opporunity record another problem is we have validation rule on Opportunity object which checks if the Opporunity has Competitior account or not.so if user inactivate any competitor account how can I bypass the aove error.I steher anything that i can do in Validation rule or something with Lookup filter criteria bacuse i can not remove the criteria.Please suggest if there would be any option besides Lookup filter Criteria...

Comment: Should it allow to inactivate the competitor in your business scenario?

Comment: If user is inactivating the Account record, you need to check if there are any Opportunities exists for this Account. If there are any such records then do not allow user to inactivate the Account record. You can write a trigger on Account object to implement this scenario.

Comment: @Sneha it does allow me to inactivate the competitor account.the problem the account that is added in opportunity,if navigate to the opportunity,on VF page it throws an error...

Comment: @Devendra this scenario I have implemented in my case but the problem is in some cases it is necessary to inactivate the Competitor Account,so even if write a code in trigger on before update event,how can I bypass the error,at a certain stage I have to inactivate the account anyhow once it is fulfilled.

Comment: Can you replace the filter with a validation rule to select only Active competitors, and which only triggers at initial stage. It should not fire once your criteria is fulfilled

Comment: @Sneha but again the question is will it throw the validation error if I make any active account which is mentioned in competitor as inactive?

Comment: What is the condition when the user is allowed to make it inactive? add this condition in your validation rule

Comment: Condition in filter is: Competitor: Account Record Type= competitor &&Competitor: Inactive=false     and the condition in Validation rule is ISBLANK(Competitor__c)

Comment: in which case is it necessary to inactivate the account? is there any criteria?

Comment: @Sneha for this particular record type there is no such criteria for now.

Comment: Yes, Trigger would restrict every time. To bypass, Validation Rule on Opportunity would be good Option. Lets you create Opportunity record with Account as "Competitor" and "Active". Add these conditions in Validation rule of Opportunity. Now on Account Object, if you try to Inactive record you will be able to do it. The Opportunity record will give error only when you try to save/update a record using apex/data loader, as Opportunity Record is no longer fits into the criteria and validation rule fire.